# referring select output as a table in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having a query and I want to perform the operation like

```
select *
from (query which i wrote) as x
where
 (select count(*)
  from x as y
  where x.location=y.location
  and x.count>=y.count)<=3;
```

It was giving error

instead of x, I can add the query which I wrote. but the query is pretty much big. when I tried the above query it is giving table doesn't exist error. is there a way to perform the above operation? kindly help me.

Comment: `x.count`? So your query contains a result column called `count`?

Comment: yes Thorsten, my query is formed joining 3 tables. and it returns location and count, to be more specific it returns location(city name) and respective count. i am trying to retrieve only top 3 counts in each city

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-use a table alias like that.  Instead, you need to copy the subquery.  Or use variables:

```
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             (@rn := if(@l = location, @rn + 1,
                        if(@l := location, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (query which i wrote) q cross join
           (select @l := '' , @rn := 0) params
      order by location, count desc
     ) q
where rn <= 3;
```

Comment: thank you Gordon Linoff, I tried your solution and it threw a error Error Code: 1051. Unknown table 'q'